# Track users views

Tags: users

I need to track what posts or pages does every logged in user view. 
I tried lots of plugins like ThreeWP, Stream, SimpleStat, User Activity, etc but all of them are admin-focused.

I DON'T need to know any plugin, themes, or any admin activity. I want to go to a specific user and see whats posts he has visited. Maybe some stats like which logged in users saw this specific posts.

Do you know something like that?
Thanks

Comment: Asking for Plugin Recommendations are considered Off-Topic here, per the [rules seen in the Help Center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Maybe it's time to hire a developer who can come up with a solution for you? If you're PHP savvy, you could use [`post_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) to track these sort of things but on a high traffic site this may be cumbersome.

Comment: I'm not asking a plugin recommendation. Plugins is what I already tried but it's not what I'm asking for. Maybe there's a service that does this or a way to make other analytic service to add this tracking. Maybe a plugin is what will solve my problem but if I'm asking here is because I don't know what are the possibilities.

Comment: You can also try to use Google Analytics by using `wp_localize_script` to send the current user id to your JavaScript, and in your JavaScript add a Google Analytics event that tracks user id and the page they are on

Comment: Interesting question, but it is overly broad as this requires a lot of code to code something like this, so in short, this can become quite a big project. Honestly, inmy opinion, I will really look for a better API to handle this, something like google analytics. Wordpress really does not provide an interface for something like this, and using postmeta can become a headache if your post count and user count get quite large. Storing all this data can clot your db